# Problems while getting absolute path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, path

I have the following file which I would like to read, as you can see its incomplete:

```
file = 'dir2/file.hdf5'
```

However, I would like to get the full path of `file` (*):

```
'/home/user/git_hub_repo/dir1/dir2/file.hdf5'
```

However, when I do:

```
from pathlib import Path
filename = Path('dir2/file.hdf5').resolve()
print(filename)
```

I get:

```
'/home/user/git_hub_repo/dir2/file.hdf5'
```

Which is wrong because a `dir1` is missing in the retrieved path, **how can I get (*) path**

Note, that in my terminal i am in:

```
/home/user/git_hub_repo/
```

Comment: Sorry, python doesn't support mind reading yet. How do you expect it to know that you want a `dir1` in there?

Comment: `resolve()` just joins the current directory to the path you gave it.  It doesn't magically know that you really meant _that file over there, with a similar name_.

Comment: I know... which is the correct way of getting that path?

Comment: What is the output of `filename.is_file()`? It's probably false as `Path()` starts from your current directory.

Comment: @Alex `false` you are right, what can I do?

Comment: @anon, you need to add `dir1` when _you_ instantiate your path.

Comment: just like that? @Alex

Comment: `filename = Path('dir1/dir2/file.hdf5').resolve()`

Comment: Ok so my problem is the definition of the path

Comment: Is the real problem that you don't know the full pathname, and you want to **search** for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current directory is

> /home/user/git_hub_repo/

and your file is in

> /home/user/git_hub_repo/dir1/dir2/file.hdf5

You should change this

> file = 'dir2/file.hdf5'

to

> file = 'dir1/dir2/file.hdf5'